# Ошибка синтакиса

Tags: jquery

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function() { 
        var data = {
            title: $('input[name=POST_TITLE]').val(),
            url: $('#post-code-text').text(),
            text: $('#LHE_iframe_LHEBlogId').contents().find('body').text()
        }
        if ($('#post-code-text').text() != '' && $('input[name=POST_TITLE]').val() != '')
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/ajax/blog_subs.php',
                dat a: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'post',
                success: function() {}
            });
        }
    };
```

Ошибка на последнюю строку "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; " в чем причина?

Comment: у вас опечатки - "dat a" вместо "data" и не закрыта круглая скобка в самом конце

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Поставьте точку с запятой в шестой строке
2. Оператор сравнения с "пустотой", лучше использовать **!==**
3. Про очепятку "**dat a**" уже сказал [[@DreamChild](/users/10162/dreamchild)](/users/10162/dreamchild)
4. Последняя строка - круглой скобки не хватает "**});**"